# howto use logbook with celery?

Tags: python, celery, logbook

I want use logbook with celery that doesn't put the log  to any worker's log file but stdout.

I use the StreamHandler like this:

```
stream_handler = StreamHandler(sys.stdout, format_string=format_str, bubble=True)
```

celery -A app.celery worker -l debug -f /log/worker-%i.log

Any log used logbook will print to stdout, but logging can write to worker-x.log file.

thx.